# Heroku deployed MERN app, shows only "Not Found"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, mern

I've written a MERN app and it works locally and pushes to heroku but when I go to the heroku app link it says only "Not Found". I've checked my package.json build script and added express route to serve static files but I'm getting the same result. The client folder is inside the root/backend folder and is made with create-react-app. Here is my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
require('dotenv').config();

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const expressSession = require('express-session');

const commentroutes = require('./routes/commentRoutes');
const postRoutes = require('./routes/postRoutes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const messageRoutes = require('./routes/messageRoutes');
const searchRoutes = require('./routes/searchRoutes');
const statusRoutes = require('./routes/statusRoutes');

const User = require('./models/user');
const PrivateMessage = require('./models/privateMessage');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: process.env.SECRET || 'local development secret',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false
  })
);

// ##### ROUTES #####
app.use('/user', userRoutes);

app.use('/post', postRoutes);

app.use('/comment', commentroutes);

app.use('/message', messageRoutes);

app.use('/search', searchRoutes);

app.use('/status', statusRoutes);

let onlineUsers = {};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  //set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));
}
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(res => {
    const expressServer = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
    console.log('listening on port 8000');

    // BEGIN SOCKET IO:
    const io = socketio(expressServer);
    io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log('online users: ', onlineUsers, 'new user: ', socket.id);
      const setUpCurrentChatUser = async () => {
        const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
        if (!token) {
          console.log('no token auth denied');
        } else {
          try {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
            // console.log('DECODED: ', decoded);
            let current_time = Date.now() / 1000;
            if (decoded.exp < current_time) {
              console.log('expired');

              // token is expired, not authorized
            } else {
              let decodedUser = await User.findOne({
                _id: decoded.tokenUser.userId
              });
              const currentUser = {
                userId: decodedUser._id,
                socketId: socket.id
              };
              onlineUsers = addUser(onlineUsers, currentUser);

              const currentUserFriendList = decodedUser.friendList;

              const modifiedFriendList = currentUserFriendList.map(friend => {
                if (friend in onlineUsers) {
                  const newFriend = {
                    friendId: friend,
                    isOnline: true,
                    socketId: onlineUsers[friend].socketId
                  };
                  return newFriend;
                } else if (!(friend in onlineUsers)) {
                  const newFriend = {
                    friendId: friend,
                    isOnline: false,
                    socketId: null
                  };
                  return newFriend;
                }
              });

              socket.emit('friendList', modifiedFriendList);
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.log('jwt error ');
          }
        }
      };

      setUpCurrentChatUser();

      const addUser = (userList, user) => {
        let newList = Object.assign({}, userList);
        newList[user.userId] = user;
        return newList;
      };

      socket.on('newPrivateMessageFromClient', async message => {
        console.log('newPrivateMessageFromClient: ', message);

        const friendId = message.currentFriend.friendId;
        const friendSocketId = onlineUsers[friendId].socketId;

        const newPrivateMessage = new PrivateMessage({
          sender: message.senderId,
          recipient: message.currentFriend.friendId,
          participants: [message.senderId, message.currentFriend.friendId],
          content: message.message
        });
        newPrivateMessage.save().then(result => {
          console.log('newPrivateMessage: ', result);

          //to friend
          io.to(`${friendSocketId}`).emit('privateMessageFromServer', result);

          //to sender
          const userSocketId = onlineUsers[message.senderId].socketId;
          console.log('USER SOCKET ID: ', userSocketId);
          io.to(`${userSocketId}`).emit('ownPrivateMessageFromServer', result);
        });
      });

      socket.on('updateFriendList', async friendList => {
        const modifiedFriendList = friendList.map(friend => {
          if (friend in onlineUsers) {
            const newFriend = {
              friendId: friend,
              isOnline: true,
              socketId: onlineUsers[friend].socketId
            };
            return newFriend;
          } else if (!(friend in onlineUsers)) {
            const newFriend = {
              friendId: friend,
              isOnline: false,
              socketId: null
            };
            return newFriend;
          }
        });

        socket.emit('friendList', modifiedFriendList);
      });

      socket.on('disconnect', async socketId => {
        try {
          const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
          const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'speakfriendandenter');
          const userId = decoded.tokenUser.userId;
          console.log(
            'DISCONNECT, socket id: ',
            socketId,
            'decoded.tokenUser.userId: ',
            decoded.tokenUser.userId
          );
          delete onlineUsers[userId];
          console.log('updated online users after disconnect: ', onlineUsers);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and here is the package.json in my backend folder/root folder:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.15.3",
    "npm": "6.9.0"
  },
  "author": "Thomas",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.1.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-session": "^1.16.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
    "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.11",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-gridfs-storage": "^3.3.0",
    "node": "^12.9.0",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^5.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: does it give any errors after building it?

Comment: no, it builds successfully when i push it. it says: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types     -> (none)
remote:        Default types for buildpack -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 37.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v13
remote:        https://mernstacksocialmedia.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Comment: try changing your `"main": "index.js"` to  `"main": "server.js"` in your package.json, rebuild, and deploy again.

Comment: I changed to "main": "server.js", and pushed to heroku master, but its still showing only 'Not Found'

Answer (score 0):

change that back to `index.js` and try this:

```
app.get('*', (request, response) => {

response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));

 });

});
```

Comment: When I added that I got this: {"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"stat","path":"/app/client/build/index.html","expose":false,"statusCode":404,"status":404}

Comment: also when i use 'git commit' now i get "Changes not staged for commit:
        modified:   client (modified content, untracked content)" but other changes seem to be successfully tracked/added/committed/pushed

Comment: @rollerpigeon ok, get rid of that and try the above

Comment: put the first two variables up top and try the last part above

Comment: ok i pasted in what you put above, it went back to saying "Not Found"

Comment: i noticed i was missing 'client' on the end of my heroku-postbuild script, i added it and tried your edit, now it is failing to build/push

Comment: it says "npm ERR! path /tmp/build_7af29c98b09666bd0ddb91da526ab54e/client/package.json" and "remote: npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file."

Comment: maybe this then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53194891/got-troubles-to-deploy-on-heroku

Comment: I got it up and running by making new folders and copying the files over and deleting the .git files and reinitializing it with git init. I noticed the upload size went from 37 MB to over 70 MB, I think what was happening is that because there was a .git file in my client folder, it was not being pushed or tracked because it wasnt added as a submodule. I'm not quite sure, though. Thank you for all of your help, I can't express enough how satisfying it is to see this thing deployed.